# How to use xargs to pass arguments as sudo to given program in terminal shell

Tags: shell

I want kill a series process like follow:(rg is a grep alternative)

```bash
ps -aux | rg "some_procs" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

but It raise an error message show I don't have permission. I also can't add sudo neither after xargs or behind xargs.(seems it will cause xargs assign argus to sudo rather kill).
How do I use sudo in this pipe link to kill those processes?

Comment: Why can't you `xargs sudo kill -9`? `argus to sudo rather kill` Great!

Comment: `... | awk '{print |"sudo kill -9 " $2}'`

Answer (score 2):

```bash
ps -aux | rg "mytmp" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

this command worked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to
[the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75406121/1699311),
if you are using GNU/Linux box, you could have use
[`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) so

```bash
sudo pkill some_procs
```

Also note that, otherwise, your can pass many PIDs to `kill` OK. You don't need all `ps` default fields, but only PID and name to filter. Last, you can skip the `rg` part because you can do it in `awk` directly.

```bash
sudo kill -9 $(ps -o pid,args | awk '$2 ~ /some_procs/ {$1}')
```